# How to secure SAM file

Tags: windows, security, ubuntu, live-cd

Is there any way to secure SAM(Security Account Manager) file from Windows in case of someone gets physical access to our pc and uses Ubuntu live CD to boot from cd and then copying our SAM file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting your `SAM File` Is a good option however as you said you can not use `Bitlocker` so you can go for the boot time passwords that would prevent the users from changing the boot order and use an alternate platform to boot and access the windows resources.

Answer (score 1):

[BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/bitlocker) can be used to secure an entire drive against accidental media loss.

Comment: idea good so +1, but I wont accept because of fact I have only windows 7 home so I can use it